# Check if response successfully got from service file Angular 7

Tags: javascript, service, angular7

[image]I am calling service from component.ts. Below is my code.

```
this.categories$ = this._categoryService.getAll().pipe();
```

Now I want to check if I got response from service file. So if I will get response then I want to do `loading = false`. I don't know what to do. How we can use subscribe in this and make `loading = false`

Answer (score 0):

I just read the helpful article ["How to never repeat the same RxJs mistakes again"](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/blitz-tips-rxjs-pipe-is-not-a-subscribe-125c89437a2c/) and it seems that the solution looks as follows:

```
this.categories$ = this._categoryService.getAll()
    .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.loading = false)
    );
```

Comment: see my updated question with a screenshot. after replacing your code I am getting the above error.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. Still not tested but this should work